# How can you export the ARM template of a logic app which includes its associated ISE?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, azureportal

How can you export the ARM template of a logic app which includes its associated ISE?

Every time I try, the template is missing the "integrationServiceEnvironment" from the "properties" collection of the "Microsoft.Logic/workflows" ...

```
"integrationServiceEnvironment": {
    "id": "[parameters('integrationServiceEnvironments_ise_eun_logicapps_0_externalid')]"
}
```

*... and I have to use the Portal, because the Visual Studio Logic App extension doesn't yet support ISE's*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, actually some relationship can't be exported by "export template". I test it and also can't find the "integrationServiceEnvironment" in arm template, but we can add it manually. When we export the template from the logic app and we want to deploy it in next time. We can add "integrationServiceEnvironment" as below before the deployment:

```
"integrationServiceEnvironment": {
    "name": "the name of your ISE",
    "id": "the resource id of your ISE",
    "type": "Microsoft.Logic/integrationServiceEnvironments"
},
```

The code above should be added under "properties" in template. Apart from this, I changed the location in template to be same as ISE which we added and I also changed the name in the template to a new name of the logic app which I want to create.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it's not me missing an option that adds the ISE property